# How to implement Java "@Default.String" in scala

Tags: scala, traits

I am really new in scala and recently wanna try to translate a java code to scala as following:

```
public interface BB extends AA {
  @Default.String("./myfile")
  String getInputFile();
}
```

My implementation is:

```
trait BB extends AA {
  def getInputFile {
    """./myfile"""
  }
}
```

But in the end when I called ***getInputFile***, it always null...
Could anyone help?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, what exactly does `@Default.string()` does? I'm not a java guy, and I tried Googling but didn't found anything. It seems to me that what it does is to provide a default implementation to the method if not overridden in the child class, am I correct?

Comment: so `./myfile` is your input file from resource directory right ?

Answer (score 4):

Your method definition is missing a `=`, so you are declaring a method that returns `Unit`. The Scala convention is not to add `get` for simple member access, and you can also lose the `{}`. So your trait looks like this:

```
trait BB extends AA {
  def inputFile = """./myfile"""
}
```

Comment: OP can also use regular quotes instead of triple quotes.